# How to do function similar to .readlines using pywinauto on a textbox?

Tags: user-interface, python-2.7, pywinauto

I have a GUI that I am automating with pywinauto. At the end of every loop, pywinauto makes the GUI display some text in a textbox (I can click and type into this textbox if I needed to) and then take a screenshot. I would like to get pywinauto to perform a simple test on the textbox to make sure the text isn't nonsense and afterwards take a screenshot. How do I get pywinauto to turn the text box into a python object that can be worked with?

Comment: Am I right, you want read the text from textbox and compare with the text you've already typed? So the question is how to read text from textbox?

Comment: It would be useful if you post some code how you type a text.